# Rebus puzzle "cancelled"

Tags: rebus, english

I have a rebus puzzle I can't figure out.
The word "Cancelled" is written with the  "CAN" angled downwards and the "CELLED" angled upwards :

```
                D
              E
            L
          L
C       E
  A   C
    N
```

What does that mean ?

Comment: Could you maybe add a visual so we can see what you are talking about?

Comment: if this is really a rebus puzzle please add the rebus tag. Unless this isn't a rebus and more of a riddle??

Comment: I'va added a visual representation, remove/edit it if this is not your puzzle

Comment: [This](/a/36138) can be an answer of interest. You might be interested to accept it.

Answer (score 45):

I think that this rebus was published in America and is

> cancelled check
>
>  But hang on -- if published in America, shouldn't it be CANCELED with one L?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what makes you think this was published in America?

Comment: @GordonAllocman I could be wrong about that, of course. But the mark that the OP described (and which Lord of Dark has now shown in text art, though that text art wasn't in the OP when I answered it) -- the mark such as the green one Puzzling.SE displays by an accepted answer -- is in Britain called a tick, not a check. And the word "check" for that slip of paper ordering a sum of money to be paid from someone's account to a named person -- is spelt "cheque" in Britain.

Comment: @RosieF Credit Mr Webster for that particular confusion.  They are both used, almost equally, in AE.  Canceled just looks wrong to me.

Comment: I think this should be accepted.

Comment: Also "cheque" is the correct spelling in countries that aren't the US.

Comment: I spell cancelled with 2 Ls and I am in the US.